# Zend Custom Routes, with parameter name only, no value

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I have a module based zend application. I am trying to route modules appropriately, based on a version number (param) defined, ie. domain.com/api/v1.

my app looks like this

```
-application
...
--modules 
----default
----api
----api2
...
```

I have a router in my bootstrap routing correctly, but to a default module, 'api'.

```
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    $router = $frontController->getRouter();

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    'api/:apiversion/:controller/:action/*',

                    array('module' => 'api',
                        'apiversion' => ':apiversion',
                        'controller' => ':controller',
                        'action' => ':action')
    );

    $router->addRoute('api', $route);
```

**How can i route based on the apiversion param, 'v1', 'v2'?**

```
domain.com/api/v2/users/id/5 =>  /api2/users/id/5
```

-Yes i understand I can have the user input domain.com/api2/ ... -not what i want.

-Yes i understand I can have the user input domain.com/api/version/2 ... -not what i want.

I will only do those if what I want can't be achieved. Thank you :)

**I figure I can do a ->getParam("v1") to see if it exists, then set the appropriate module, unless there is a pretty, dynamic way**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing something like that :

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

$router = $frontController->getRouter();

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'api/v1/:controller/:action/*',

            array('module' => 'api',
                'apiversion' => 'v1',
                'controller' => ':controller',
                'action' => ':action')
);

$router->addRoute('api', $route);
$route2 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'api/v2/:controller/:action/*',

            array('module' => 'api2',
                'apiversion' => 'v2',
                'controller' => ':controller',
                'action' => ':action')
);

$router->addRoute('api2', $route2);
```

Regards

mimiz

Comment: hmm. tried something almost similar at first, but I was getting api:v1 resource not found issues (ACL implemented). But now it is working of course :p

Comment: Also, was trying to go for a generic version route, without defining the version number, but this will work.